# Is it possible to change the name of a build based on the branch name in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Most of my builds are from either feature branches or develop, and so I tend to use a known build variable to track the build number such as:

[image: Build Variables]

```
variables:
- group: BuildVars

name: $(BuildPrefix)$(Rev:r)
```

This works and provides me with a nicely formatted build version that I can then follow through into releases, etc:

[image: Build number as name in Build Pipeline]

[image: Build number as name in Release Pipeline]

However, when we're planning a release, we name our branches after the release, for example: `release/1.1`, and I'd like to have the build name reference that instead of the hardcoded (previous) version.

I know that I can reference the branch name via the `Build.SourceBranch` variable, but I don't see an obvious way to read and modify that outside of a build step, by which time I believe it's too late? I don't really want to have to manually change the `BuildPrefix` variable until the release has been deployed out to production.

Building on from this would then be the ability to append appropriate pre-release tags, etc. based on the branch name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the name of a build based on the branch name in Azure Pipelines?

The answer is yes.

The solution we currently use is add a `Run Inline Powershell` task to update build number based on the `Build_SourceBranchName`:

```
$branch = $Env:Build_SourceBranchName
Write-Host "Current branch is $branch"
if ($branch -eq "Dev")
{
    Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$DevBuildNumber"
}
elseif ($branch -eq "Beta")
{
    Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$BetaBuildNumber"
}
elseif ($branch -eq "Test")
{
    Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$TestBuildNumber"
}
```

Check the [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) during the build for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using this approach is it possible to use `$(Rev:r)` for a run value? As this seems to only work with the 'name' property.

Answer (score 3):

you can always update the build name during the execution of a build using this:

```
- pwsh: |
    Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]value_goes_here"
```

so you could calculate the value in the same (or previous step) and update the build name with that value

Comment: Cheers, I'll give that a go ;)